# Melt dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

```
d = {'key': [1,2,3], 'a': [True,True, False], 'b': [False,False,True]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Current melt function is:

```
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['key'], var_name = 'letter', value_name = 'Bool')
df2 = df2.query('Bool == True')
```

Is there a way to incorporate that 'True' condition in the melt function. As I continue to add entries to my df and I have hundreds of columns, I assume it's much less costly to pull only the values I need instead of melting the entire df and then filtering. Any ideas?

Comment: melt the filter is right way to do it

Comment: Are you saying how I have it is the right way to do it? Don't understand

Comment: Yes, that is correct way

Comment: My question was whether there was a way to only pull what I need ie include a condition, as I assume it would be more efficient. I understand that my current method works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pd.melt instead. Factor in replacement of False with NaN and dropna() eventually.

```
pd.melt(df.replace(False, np.nan), id_vars=['key'],var_name = 'letter', value_name = 'Bool').dropna()



    key letter  Bool
0    1      a  True
1    2      a  True
5    3      b  True
```

Comment: is it more efficient? tests?

Comment: @sammywemmy, yes, with the same speeds as I see

Comment: cool; kindly share

Comment: please see benchmarks in my post fyi.

Comment: I do like this solution since now it becomes a one liner. However, pandas is still going to melt the entire dataframe and then remove rows, right? So this technically wouldn't avoid potentially running into out of memory issues right?

Comment: This is highly vectorized meaning it is not row by row operation but operates on the series all at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the non key cols first, melt the results and concat the melted rows back. See the following;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

d = {'key': [1,2,3], 'a': [True,True, False], 'b': [False,False,True]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

start_time = time.time()
key_column_name = 'key'
key_column_loc = list(df.columns).index(key_column_name)
filtered_frame = None
for letter in [s for s in list(df.columns) if s != key_column_name]:
  true_booleans = np.nonzero(df[letter].values)[0]
  melted_df = df.iloc[true_booleans][[key_column_name, letter]].reset_index(drop=True).melt(id_vars=[key_column_name], var_name = 'letter', value_name = 'Bool')
  if filtered_frame is None:
    filtered_frame = melted_df
  else:
    filtered_frame = pd.concat((filtered_frame, melted_df), axis = 0)
end_time = time.time()
print(filtered_frame, '\n\n', end_time - start_time, 'seconds!')
```

> Output

```
   key letter  Bool
0    1      a  True
1    2      a  True
0    3      b  True 

 0.011133432388305664 seconds!
```

Compared to your code, it is slower (your score is 0.008090734481811523 seconds!), however as the rows increase, I would expect that above way of doing it will be more efficient. Looking forward for the results.

> Regarding the discussion on speed (Benchmarks)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Benchmark Tests 
d = {'key': [1,2,3], 'a': [True,True, False], 'b': [False,False,True]}
df_initial = pd.DataFrame(d)

data_size = [10, 100, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000, 1000000, 5000000, 10000000, 50000000]
scores_current = []
scores_golden_lion  = []
scores_sammywemmy = []
scores_wwnde = []
scores_slybot = []

for n_rows in data_size:

  df = df_initial.sample(n=n_rows, replace=True).reset_index(drop=True)

  ## @Current method 
  start_time = time.time()
  df_current = df.melt(id_vars=['key'], var_name = 'letter', value_name = 'Bool')
  df_current = df_current.query('Bool == True')
  end_time = time.time()
  scores_current.append(end_time-start_time)

  ## @Golden Lion
  start_time = time.time()
  df_golden_lion = df.melt(id_vars=['key'], var_name = 'letter', value_name = 'Boolean')
  df_golden_lion= df_golden_lion.drop(df_golden_lion.index[df_golden_lion['Boolean'] == False])
  end_time = time.time()
  scores_golden_lion.append(end_time-start_time)

  ## @sammywemmy
  start_time = time.time()
  box = df.iloc[:, 1:]
  len_df = len(df)
  letters = np.tile(box.columns, (len_df,1))[box]
  df_sammywemmy = pd.DataFrame({'key':df.key.array, 
                                'letter' : letters, 
                                'Bool' : [True]*len_df})
  end_time = time.time()
  scores_sammywemmy.append(end_time-start_time)

  ## @wwnde 
  start_time = time.time()
  df_wwnde = pd.melt(df.replace(False, np.nan), id_vars=['key'],var_name = 'letter', value_name = 'Bool').dropna()
  end_time = time.time()
  scores_wwnde.append(end_time-start_time)

  ## @Slybot 
  start_time = time.time()
  key_column_name = 'key'
  key_column_loc = list(df.columns).index(key_column_name)
  filtered_frame = None
  for letter in [s for s in list(df.columns) if s != key_column_name]:
    true_booleans = np.nonzero(df[letter].values)[0]
    melted_df = df.iloc[true_booleans][[key_column_name, letter]].melt(id_vars=[key_column_name], var_name = 'letter', value_name = 'Bool')
    if filtered_frame is None:
      filtered_frame = melted_df
    else:
      filtered_frame = pd.concat((filtered_frame, melted_df), axis = 0)
  end_time = time.time()
  scores_slybot.append(end_time-start_time)

plt.plot(data_size, scores_current, label = "Current method")
plt.plot(data_size, scores_golden_lion, label = "Golden Lion")
plt.plot(data_size, scores_sammywemmy, label = "sammywemmy")
plt.plot(data_size, scores_wwnde, label = "wwnde")
plt.plot(data_size, scores_slybot, label = "Slybot")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Benchmarks]

**Interesting to see that none of the other answers can beat the originally suggested method with a dataset of 500,000 rows! Until 200,000 rows sammywemmy's method is a clear winner though.**

Answer (score 0):

The `melt` and `filter` step is efficient though, I'd probably stick with `loc` instead of `query`, especially if your data is not that large (<200_000 rows)

Another option is to skip `melt`, use `numpy`, and build a new dataframe:

```py
box = df.iloc[:, 1:]
len_df = len(df)
letters = np.tile(box.columns, (len_df,1))[box]
pd.DataFrame({'key':df.key.array, 
              'letter' : letters, 
              'Bool' : [True]*len_df})

   key letter  Bool
0    1      a  True
1    2      a  True
2    3      b  True
```

Comment: Plot this versus mine, seems much slower

Comment: care to share. and it stays slower as the size increases?

Comment: Yes it does, it  much slower, have you tried to plot it?

Comment: no, just did a %timeit

Comment: please see benchmarks in my post fyi.

Answer (score 0):

melt moves column data and stacks it vertically resulting in two columns: the variable name of the column being stacked and the value column name.

```
d = {'key': [1,2,3], 'a': [True,True, False], 'b': [False,False,True],'c':['Batchelor','Masters','Doctorate']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['key'], var_name = 'letter', value_name = 'Boolean')

df2=df2.drop(df2.index[df2['Boolean'] == False])

print(df2)
```

output

```
  key letter    Boolean
0    1      a       True
1    2      a       True
5    3      b       True
6    1      c  Batchelor
7    2      c    Masters
8    3      c  Doctorate
​
```